# Read nested json file into R and write to csv

Tags: r, json, dataframe

How can I read in [this](https://data.covidactnow.org/latest/us/states/AL.OBSERVED_INTERVENTION.timeseries.json) json file from the COVID Act Now API, convert to data frame, and write to CSV?

It seems to be in some special nested json format and I am getting this error in R

`AL <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(file = "https://data.covidactnow.org/latest/us/states/AL.OBSERVED_INTERVENTION.timeseries.json"))`

> Error in fromJSON(file =
> "https://data.covidactnow.org/latest/us/states/AL.OBSERVED_INTERVENTION.timeseries.json")
> : argument "txt" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(jsonlite)

AL <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(txt = "https://data.covidactnow.org/latest/us/states/AL.OBSERVED_INTERVENTION.timeseries.json"))
```

Notice the name of the argument: `txt`, not `file`.

Comment: It does not work in 2023.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0